# Empty network dataset creation in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm trying to create a new network dataset via ArcCatalog in a SDE database. I've imported a street featureclass into my dataset, go to create the network dataset with all the default options. After I hit go, it spins for a minute then comes back saying the creation is complete, but that "the new network dataset has been created no features were found within the extent of the network dataset."

What causes this and how do I resolve?

Comment: How did you import it?  Do you think you somehow managed to import a featureclass whose spatial reference differs from that of the featuredataset containing it?

Comment: Feature Class to Feature Class. Wouldn't the spatial reference of the featuredataset override whatever I import?

Comment: As a test, maybe try creating a new featuredataset.  When prompted to choose a spatial reference, browse to the spatial reference of your streets featureclass.  Then try creating the network dataset.

Answer (score 2):

From [resource center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000000w000000):

> If you are creating a geodatabase-based network dataset, all feature
>   classes participating as sources in a network should be present in one
>   feature dataset.

That could be an issue in your case. If not you should first [create feature dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002300000002000000.htm) and move your network data there. Then execute new network dataset creation [inside feature dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000005t000000):

[image]

Comment: I'm doing exactly that